# pdo exception when trying to access firebird

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework2, firebird, firebird2.5

I have to access firebird with php and zend framework 2 and I'm having the following error:

```
 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver /Pdo/Statement.php:187

Message:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -204 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 Table  unknown pessoa At line 1, column 19 

Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver /Pdo/Statement.php(187): PDO->prepare('SELECT "pessoa"...')
#1 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php(213): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->prepare()
#2 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(233): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute()
#3 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#5 /var/www/html/cad/module/Pessoa/src/Pessoa/Model/PessoaTable.php(18): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#6 /var/www/html/cad/module/Pessoa/src/Pessoa/Controller/PessoaController.php(26): Pessoa\Model\PessoaTable->fetchAll()
#7 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Pessoa\Controller\PessoaController->indexAction()
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/html/cad/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/html/cad/public/index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

Global.php

```
return array(
 'db' => array(
     'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'dsn'            => 'firebird:dbname=/opt/bancos/teste.fdb',   //array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true),
     /*'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
     ),*/
 ),
 'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                 => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
 );
?>
```

local.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
            'username' => 'sysdba',
            'password' => 'masterkey',
    ),
);
?>
```

PessoaController.php

```
 public function indexAction()
 {

        return new ViewModel(array(
                'pessoas' => $this->getPessoaTable()->fetchAll(),
        ));


  }
```

PessoaTable.php

```
public function fetchAll()
 {
            try{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
            } catch(Exception $e){
              $e->getMessage();
            }
    return $resultSet;
  }
```

and here is the method getPessoaTable()

```
public function getPessoaTable()
 {
    if (!$this->pessoaTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->pessoaTable = $sm->get('Pessoa\Model\PessoaTable');
    }
    return $this->pessoaTable;
 }
```

I have configured pdo_firebird.so in php. And it shows up on phpinfo()

Comment: can you show this method? getPessoaTable();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the error is: *"Table  unknown pessoa"*. You are selecting from a table `pessoa`, no such table exists according to Firebird. The fact that `pessoa` is lower case in the error message shows you are using quoted identifiers. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive in Firebird. Unquoted identifiers are upper cased to make them case insensitive.

So this error either means the table really doesn't exist, or - as you use quoted identifiers - the table name is actually `PESSOA`. The rules Firebird uses for quoted/unquoted identifiers will make `SELECT ... FROM pessoa` work, but `SELECT ... FROM "pessoa"` fail.

I don't know PDO, so I can't give a PDO specific help, but I hope this narrows it down for you.

Comment: You're right, the trouble was just it you told.

So my solutions was change the name of table on my Module.php in the getServiceConfig method from pessoa to PESSOA. Very thank you!!